# Почему деление на ассемблере отличается от C#?

Tags: ассемблер

Есть функция генерации кода, хочу перевести её на C#. Но возник вопрос:

Почему тут EAX=00001303?

```
MOV BL, 1A           // 26
MOV AL, 61           // 97
DIV BL
```

А когда пишу на C#

```
int a=0x1A;
int b=0x61;
b/=a;
```

Получается, что b = 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что частное 03h попадает в AL, а остаток 13h в AH. AH и AL вместе составляют регистр AX.

Answer (score 3):

> Почему тут EAX=00001303?

Потому что в AL (младшую половину AX) помещается частное, а в AH (старшую половину AX) - остаток.

> b/=a;

А здесь выполняется простое целочисленное деление.